# How to link Login Button to another page

Tags: react-native

Sorry if this is a simple question but I can't seem to get it to work.

Currently I have a button that should return Main (the main page of my app) by calling the onPress function.

```
class Button extends Component{
    onTap(){
        return <Main/>;
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={this.onTap}
                    style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this2.props.onTap()')
```

Can someone help me out here? I don't know what's wrong

Comment: Are you really giving your full code? I cannot see any `props.onTap` in your code...

Comment: @OlivierM i don't have a props.onTap in my code. Mabye it is because I have this     constructor(props){
        super(props)
    } in my main file index.android.js?

Comment: Im not sure I understand, do you actually want to navigate to your component or load it into your actual one?

Comment: @NinetyHH This button is on my login page. I want it to load into the main page of my app. So the app goes like splash screen -> login page -> main app

Answer (score 0):

```
class Button extends Component{
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state={isLogin:false}
}

onTap(){
    this.setState({isLogin:true});
}

render(){
    if(this.state.isLogin){
        return <Main/>;
    }


    return(
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.onTap}
                style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}};
```

please go through docs about JSX first~

Comment: I'm not really sure why i'm getting this this error: undefined is not a function(evaluating 'this.setState((isLogin:true))')

Comment: if i add on .bind(this) like so: onPress={this.onTap.bind(this)}, the button just disappears.

Comment: I was about to suggest using the development tools at your disposal to find out what's happening, but If you're as new to react as it might seem from your question, you should probably be reading docs.

Comment: @corse32 can you show me a working code? I'm really stumped. Tyreal Gray's solution is not working at all